# Sitecore item name being auto-mapped to "Name" field in Glass Mapper

Tags: glass-mapper

We're using interfaces for our models with `[SitecoreType(AutoMap=true)]`. The templates we're using (for a refit, we didn't create them) have "Name" fields, but when I just declare `string Name {get; set;}` it's grabbing the Sitecore item name and not the Name field defined in the template. I have the template name field being declared with the SitecoreInfo property to a different "ItemName" field to prevent conflicts.

We've used the Name field before in other templates, thinking it was pulling from the template and not the item name, so I don't know if this is a change in the latest Glass Mapper or something we didn't previously notice.

For now, I'm having our developers use the `SitecoreField("Name")` attribute and call the field something like "NameField" - this is getting the correct field, so we have a workaround. But I was curious if this is something that changed, if it's been that way and I hadn't noticed, or if this is a bug and "Name" should map to a field template first, and only if there is no field with that appellation use the item's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain property names do trigger that - same as Id gets automapped to the ID of the Sitecore element. To get around that you would simply need to map the Name property normally using attribute / fluent configuration.